# WiX bundle installer - Hiding a package in Programs And Features

Tags: wix, bundle

I am creating a bundle installer using WiX, and I have chained several MSIs and an .exe installer in it.  Is it possible to hide the .exe package from Programs and Features?  I would like to have only my installer appear in Programs and Features, but the .exe installer package is also appearing there currently.  I have tried setting the DisplayName property of the .exe package to an empty string, but it looks like that is not allowed.

Comment: You have to see if the xxx.exe will take a direction on that. Try `xxx.exe /?` Like any program you run, it does whatever it wants. If you want to ask about it, please [edit] to say what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the DisableModify and DisableRemove on your bundle to "yes" will keep your bundle from displayed in ARP.

From [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/bundle.html)

Comment: I don't want to hide the bundle, I want to hide one of the .exe packages that my bundle installs.  My research online has indicated that WiX doesn't support that, but I'd like to confirm.